# push_back() in std::basic_string vs sequence containers

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Sequence containers (`deque`, `list`, `vector`) have the following signatures for `push_back`:

```
void push_back (const value_type& val);
void push_back (value_type&& val);
```

But `basic_string` has the following signature for `push_back`:

```
void push_back(CharT ch);
```

Notice the absence of reference: the argument is `CharT` not `const CharT&` or `CharT&&`.

The [standards say](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) that `basic_string` satisfies the requirements of [SequenceContainer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/SequenceContainer), which dictates that a container's (call it `X`) `push_back` should be defined to accept:

- `t`, an lvalue or const rvalue of type `X::value_type`
- `rv`, a non-const rvalue of type `X::value_type`

It is not immediately clear to me, how.
Does anyone see how? Thanks.

Comment: Is there a typedef for CharT?

Comment: The various standards have always said that `basic_string` is a container, but it never *completely* fulfilled all the requirements. In this case, passing a `char` by value is probably good enough to match the functionality (even if the signature is slightly different).

Comment: @Carlos: `CharT == std::char_type<CharT>::type` should hold.  

@BoPersson: But I can always define my own `CharT` to satisfy `std::char_traits`; and for them may be passing by value & by reference would make significant difference in terms of performance.
Or does the `std::char_traits` prevent me from defining `CharT` in such a way?

Comment: Aside from it being a much better solution for strings, I don't see a contradiction to what you wrote (I don't have access to the standard at the moment ). Basic_string's push_back DOES accept l- and r- values. Does it actually specify the function signature?

Comment: [Here is a proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-closed.html#718) to say that `basic_string` is not  a container, but the standards committee chose to modify the container requirements instead. This has been going on for a long time.

Comment: @MikeMB. I don't think it does. Syntactically, you could have reference as an argument; but I think the value is copied, even if you try to pass references. For example, try to `push_back` a reference to a var and then modify the string to see if the original variable is modified.

Comment: @BoPersson: I see. Thank you! If you would like to answer-ify your comment, I would be happy to 'accept' it.

Comment: `basic_string` satisfies the [standard container requirements](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Container) from what the standard says but to me it seems that `basic_string` gives more importance to what is contained in it as it is a container only for POD types. i.e those fundamental types or plain structs/classes without constructors, destructors or virtual functions.You can put those into it and get an iterator to it as if it was a normal container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR:** Value parameters **accepts both r- and l- values**, so the function signature satisfies the requirements in the standard and it would be plain stupid to define the function signature to pass-by-reference.

---

On the question why pass-by-value was chosen over pass by reference (why `std::basic_string` is supposed to satisfy the sequence container requirements at all is another discussion on its own):

For 99.999% of the usecases (`char`, `wchar`, `char32_t`,... etc.) passing `CharT` by value will be at least as efficient as passing by reference and (ignoring inlining) in the vast majority of cases, it would even be less efficient to use a reference simply because it adds indirection and a pointer is bigger than most char-like types (the exact tradeoffs depend on the compiler, calling convention, architecture etc.).

My personal opinion: If you have a usecase, where

- it is more efficent to pass CharT by reference
- you actually care about the performance difference
- `std::vector<CharT>` isn't good enough

you should role your own string anyway, because your requirements and/or circumstances are so special that non of the common standard library implementations will be a good fit, regardless of the function signature.

Comment: In my opinion, `basic_string` should be an alias for something like a specialized `vector<CharT>`; just like `vector<bool>` is a specialized one.

Comment: @SaswatPadhi: Actually, I believe that specializing a container (especially the interface) for any member type is a mistake (maybe a case for std::map and const char* keys could be made) and the `vector<bool>` specialization should have been it's own type in the first place. In the case of string vs. vector: They are usually used in and optimized for different scenarios and I believe this should be reflected by them being different types. Especially a string is and should be something different than a raw memory buffer(*). If you want to work with them in a gneric way you can use iterators.

Comment: (*) of course this would be less if an issue, if  C++ wasn't lacking a distinct byte/raw memory type

Answer (score 3):

I think that is because the simplicity of the type `CharT`. It does need to be passed by `reference` and since it was not passed by `reference` there is no need to the `const` keyword.

In the opposite `std::vector` or `std::list` may contain a very expensive to copy object. So, it should be passed by `reference` and then the `const` is essential.

Comment: Sure. I see. But is such simplicity always guaranteed? What about user-defined `CharT` satisfying `std::char_traits`?

Comment: I do not really know much about the standards. It was just a kind of guess. But for your question, I think who should define his own CharT should make sure that it is lightweight. Exactly like when defining a custom-iterator, you should know that it would be passed by value so you should make it as light as possible.

Comment: @SaswatPadhi CharT should be TriviallyCopyable, so it could be copied by `memcpy`, so you cannot have clever stealing move constructor anyway.

Comment: Right! Thanks. So `char_traits` does restrict CharT from being `move`-able. I see.